# How do I stop css rotate back to face before expected animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to simulate the animation of flips of a coin with JS & CSS.

I guess the keys are transform-style, backface-visibility, rotateY, animation-fill-mode and transform in CSS as well as Math.random in JS.

If the coin is the heads, everything is OK.

If the coin is tail, clicking the button will flip it to head and then start the expected flipping animation.

How do I make it start flipping animation directly from the tail?

```js
const coin = document.querySelector('#coin');
const button = document.querySelector('#flip');
const status = document.querySelector('#status');
const heads = document.querySelector('#headsCount');
const tails = document.querySelector('#tailsCount');

let headsCount = 0;
let tailsCount = 0;


function deferFn(callback, ms) {
  setTimeout(callback, ms); 
}

function processResult(result) {
   if (result === 'heads') {
      headsCount++;
      heads.innerText = headsCount;
    } else {
      tailsCount++;
      tails.innerText = tailsCount;
    }
    status.innerText = result.toUpperCase();
}

function flipCoin() {
  coin.setAttribute('class', '');
  const random = Math.random();
  const result = random < 0.5 ? 'heads' : 'tails';
 deferFn(function() {
   coin.setAttribute('class', 'animate-' + result);
   deferFn(processResult.bind(null, result), 2900);
 }, 100);
}

button.addEventListener('click', flipCoin);
```

```css
h2 {
  margin: .25rem;
}

div.container {
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

button {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: skyblue;
}

#coin {
  position: relative;
  width: 15rem;
  height: 15rem;
  margin: 2rem 0rem;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;

}

#coin div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background-size: contain;
  position: absolute;
}

.heads {
    background-image: url("https://en.numista.com/catalogue/photos/inde/2311-original.jpg");
}

.animate-heads {
  animation: flipHeads 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes flipHeads {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(1800deg);
  }
}

.tails {
    background-image: url("https://en.numista.com/catalogue/photos/inde/3165-original.jpg");
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.animate-tails {
  animation: flipTails 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes flipTails {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(1620deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <h2>Confused about your life decision? Just flip this coin!</h2>
  <h2>Btw, don't forget to assign something to both sides.</h2>
  <p>And don't take your life decision based on this stupid coin flip. I was kidding.</p>
  <div id="coin" class=''>
    <div id="heads" class="heads"></div>
    <div id="tails" class="tails"></div>
  </div>
  <button id="flip">Flip this thing</button>
  <p>Heads: <span id="headsCount">0</span> Tails: <span id="tailsCount">0</span></p>
  <p><span id="status"></span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css property:

```
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```